# Comparing two files using BeyondCompare - check for content

Tags: beyondcompare4

I have two text files containing many lines of data (they are just some linux paths). The order of the paths are different in both files. I need Beyond Compare to compare the files based on content. Right now, it is checking line by line and pointing out errors if the same content is not present in the corresponding lines. I want beyondcompare to go through the entire file before saying that some path is missing. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Beyond Compare 4 sort the files before comparison. Open the files in the Text Compare, then click the dropdown on the right side of the **Format** toolbar button and select **Sorted**.